# pandas: how to call read_gbq() with non-verbose output

Tags: python, pandas

How do I call `read_gbq` with non-verbose output?

I've tried:

```
 df = pd.io.gbq.read_gbq(query_str, GBQ_PROJECT_ID, verbose=False)
```

But I get an error:

```
read_gbq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'
```

Works fine without the `verbose=False` argument.

I'm not sure [from the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.gbq.read_gbq.html) what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE: I'm using pandas 
0.16.2 inside ipython. Here is the full traceback.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-3d71f83c5920> in <module>()
     32 #     print query_str
---> 33     df = pd.io.gbq.read_gbq(query_str, GBQ_PROJECT_ID, verbose=False)
     34 #     print df.head()

TypeError: read_gbq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of pandas? I checked the source code, and `verbose` is a valid parameter.  What is the full traceback?

Comment: I think it's probably the version, as you suggest. I'm not sure how to upgrade the packages used by ipython - I've done `pip install --upgrade pandas` but it hasn't helped - but I'll try to do this.

Comment: If you are using Anaconda, you can try `conda update pandas`.